# Setting up a startdate and a stopdate based on current date using Orbeon

Tags: date, xpath, orbeon

I am using Orbeon to create forms for self services.

I have two date fields, what I want to set up an initial value for based on the current date.
My startdate must be set up as the 1th of january in the year before current year, and my stopdate must be set up as the 31th of December in the year before current year.

That is if current date is 20211020, my startdate should be set to 20200101 and my stopdate should be set to 20201231.

I have tried:
(current-date() - xs:yearMonthDuration('P8M') - xs:yearMonthDuration('P1Y'))

but this just sets the date to 20200220.

I am manipulating my control setting for the startdate and stopdate, setting a Formula as the Intial Value to get my dates set up.

I dont think that I should use xs:yearMonthDuration, but how do I get my issue solved, and what should I use instead?

Regards Helle

Comment: I've put some expressions in my answer below, but just let me know if this isn't working for you, or if I misunderstood your question. -Alex

Answer (score 1):

The following expression should do it:

- January 1st of last year: `concat(year-from-date($date) - 1, '-01-01')`
- December 31st of last year: `concat(year-from-date($date) - 1, '-12-31')`

Which will give the following, and you can also test with [this form](https://gist.github.com/avernet/8d28e27947596eef4677f59342a2148e) which source you can paste in Form Builder.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution - it has helped me solving my issue :-)

Comment: I just didn't want to manipulate the XML, so I manipulated my control setting for the startdate and stopdate, setting a Formula as the Intial Value to get my dates set up. I made the following statements, and they solved my issue:

Comment: concat(year-from-date(current-date()) - 1, '-01-01')

Comment: concat(year-from-date(current-date()) - 1, '-31-12')

Comment: Excellent @HMFN, I'm glad that did the trick, and thanks for the update. -Alex